# How can I use bigint with C#?

Tags: c#, biginteger

I work to implement an [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29) key algorithm. But I couldn't use a 2048-bit value. How I can use it?

I want to use big integer.

Comment: Usually RSA key algorithms work on 8 bits at a time.  Your key would be placed in a byte array with 8 indexes.

Comment: not duplicate. ı do not want to use long or int64. they do not enough for me

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `System.Numerics.BigInteger` (add a reference to System.Numerics assembly). As mentioned in the comments this might not be the right approach though.

Comment: Indeed, BigInteger is the way to go. Minor note: it's only available in .NET 4.0 and higher.

Answer (score 9):

Here's using `BigInteger`. This method Prints Numbers in the Fibonacci Sequence up to `n`.

```
public static void FibonacciSequence(int n)
{
    /** BigInteger easily holds the first 1000 numbers in the Fibonacci Sequence. **/
    List<BigInteger> fibonacci = new List<BigInteger>();
    fibonacci.Add(0);
    fibonacci.Add(1);
    BigInteger i = 2;
    while(i < n)
    {                
        int first = (int)i - 2;
        int second = (int) i - 1;

        BigInteger firstNumber =  fibonacci[first];
        BigInteger secondNumber = fibonacci[second];
        BigInteger sum = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        fibonacci.Add(sum);
        i++;
    }         

    foreach (BigInteger f in fibonacci) { Console.WriteLine(f); }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Native support for big integers has been introduced in .NET 4.0. Just add an assembly reference to `System.Numerics`, add a `using System.Numerics;` declaration at the top of your code file, and you’re good to go. The type you’re after is [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

[`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) is available in .NET 4.0 or later. [There are some third-party implementations as well](http://biginteger.codeplex.com/) (In case you are using an earlier version of the framework).

Answer (score 1):

Better use `System.Numerics.BigInteger`.