# how can i convert hexadecimal value to biginteger?

Tags: c#, biginteger

I mean how can I convert my hexadecimal values to biginteger ?

for example i use this :

```
string value="A1";
BigInteger bi=new BigInteger(value,16);
```

bi =161; this is true? So how can I convert back it to "A1"?

thanks..

Comment: Little bit confused which BigInteger you use that has this constructor

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar - The answers you have gotten are about `System.Numerics.BigInteger` that is in the .NET 4.0 framework library. Are you using a different one? If so, which one (links please).

Comment: In your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624815/how-can-i-use-bigint-with-c) 4 answers recommended using `BigInteger` from the .NET framework library. Why didn't you use that?

Comment: @meandmycode The Java class BigInteger has such a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.Format` supports this:

```
String.Format("0:x", 161);
```

Working example:

```
        string value="A1";
        BigInteger bi = BigInteger.Parse(value, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        string newVal = string.Format("{0:x}", bi);
        //newVal is a1
```

UPDATE:
The above suggestion is valid for the `BigInteger` implementation in the `System.Numerics` namespace of .NET

Comment: I do not have Parse method. ?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar - I will ask again. Where does the `BigInteger` class you are using coming from? Please provide a link.

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar have you tagged your question wrongly. You probably meant  to tag it with the java tag?

Comment: @PenchoIlchev - He may have meant this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2728/C-BigInteger-Class

Comment: @Oded Could be since he cannot find the BigInteger.Parse method but seems to have no problem finding string.Format

Comment: @PenchoIlchev - `String.format` is how you would do it in Java, so it _may_ be Java as well. Or something else. Without confirmation from the OP, there is no way to know.

Comment: The implementation in the code project have ToHexString method.

Comment: It might have been this one: http://biginteger.codeplex.com/releases/view/16762 - it was linked to from his last question.

Comment: @Oded This one also has ToHexString method which uses StringBuilder.AppendFormat

Answer (score 1):

To convert back the BigInteger to hexadecimal string you can do in this way :

```
string value= bi.ToString("X");
```

Comment: it is error me. like this : The best overloaded method match for 'BigInteger.ToString(int)' has some invalid argument

Answer (score 1):

[`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268341.aspx) is overridden in `BigInteger`:

```
bi.ToString("X")
```

Comment: it is error me. like this : The best overloaded method match for 'BigInteger.ToString(int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar - Where are you finding an override that takes an `int`? Post the _exact_ code you are trying. Also - stop posting the exact same comment to everyone who answered. It is annoying.