# The biggest number in C

Tags: c

```
scanf("%d",&a);
for(b=1;b<=a;++b)
{
    c*=b;
}
printf("%lu",c);
```

I want to get the answer of 100!
factorial of 100. 
how can I get this? ( I wanna get a bigger range of numbers) 
Cant we have the number limit to infinity?

Comment: So, what is the point of `c#` and `java` tags?

Comment: Assuming you use C# you can read the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624815/how-can-i-use-bigint-with-c). In Java you can use `java.math.BigInteger`.

Comment: You can't have infinite integer range, because your computer does not have infinite memory to store it.

Comment: 100! = 9332621544394415268169923885626670049071596826438162146859 29638952175999932299156089414639761565182862536979208272237582511852109168 64000000000000000000000000.  I got it from the code in BLUEPIXY's answer and verified it.

Answer (score 23):

Max integer range is, on just about every (modern) platform, `2^31 - 1` (although, by the standard, `int` is only required to be at least 16 bits). For your given platform, it'll be defined as `INT_MAX` in `<limits.h>`.

`100!` will obviously far exceed this. To calculate something this large in `C`, you'll need a big integer library, such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Just as a cautionary note, if you decide to try and use a `double` (which can hold numbers of this size), you will get the wrong answer due to precision loss. This is easy to spot - on my machine, the last digits are `48`, which is obviously nonsense: `100!` must be divisible by 100, hence must have `00` as the last two digits.

Comment: You *can* actually compute it without using GMP library. PostgreSQL supports unlimited precision integer arithmetic. Exact value is here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/991

Comment: @mvp What does that have to do with being able to compute it in `C`? You can compute it in Python, Lisp, Haskell, Java, C#. None of that means squat if you're limited to `C`.

Comment: I was just having fun. And BTW, PostgreSQL is written in C. So, you can extract unlimited precision functions from its source.

Comment: It actually ends in 000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#if __STDC_VERSION__>=199901L
#include <inttypes.h>
#else
#define PRIu16 "hu"
#endif

typedef struct _unums {
    size_t size;
    uint16_t *nums;//array 
} UNums;

void UNums_init(UNums *num, uint16_t n){
    num->nums = (uint16_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint16_t));
    num->nums[0] = n;
    num->size = 1;
}

void UNums_mul(UNums *num, uint16_t n){
    uint16_t carry = 0;
    size_t i;

    for(i=0;i<num->size;++i){
        uint32_t wk = n;
        wk = wk * num->nums[i] + carry;
        num->nums[i] = wk % 10000;
        carry = wk / 10000;
    }
    if(carry){
        num->size += 1;
        num->nums = (uint16_t*)realloc(num->nums, num->size * sizeof(uint16_t));
        num->nums[i] = carry;
    }
}

void UNums_print(UNums *num){
    size_t i = num->size;
    int w = 0;
    do{
        --i;
        printf("%0*" PRIu16, w, num->nums[i]);
        if(!w) w = 4;
    }while(i!=0);
}

void UNum_drop(UNums *num){
    free(num->nums);
    num->nums = NULL;
}

int main( void ){
    UNums n;
    uint16_t i;

    UNums_init(&n, 1);
    for(i=2;i<=100;++i)
        UNums_mul(&n, i);
    UNums_print(&n);//100!
    UNum_drop(&n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Too bad Visual Studio does not have inttypes.h

Comment: Thanks! I got it working, I had to typecast the malloc and realloc functions as well.

Comment: @raxman It will from being compiled in `C++`. There is no need for cast in `C`. But I was fixed either as good. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I see, this is a strictly C question/answer.

Comment: lovely answer - who says you can't get bignums in a few lines of C!

Answer (score 1):

For small numbers you better use `unsigned long long` than `int`. But still you have limit on the biggest number you can use for `a`. You could try `double` or `float` but you might get precession error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GMP library](https://gmplib.org/)

Install with:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

main.c:

```c
#include <gmp.h>

void f() tooBigForYourShell {
    mpz_t n;                     // declare a big n number
    mpz_init_set_ui(n,0);        // assign 0 as starting value
    mpz_setbit(n, 1UL << 24);    // set bit 2^24 (index 2^24 and not 24...) as 1.
    gmp_printf("%Zd\n", n);      // display the result
}

int main() {
    tooBigForYourShell();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with:

```
gcc main.c -lgmp && ./a.out
```

```
???
```

```
profit, enjoy your 2^(2^24) number on stdout.
```

[image]
*NB: There are much more digits before...*

You could [theoretically](https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-discuss/2012-April/005020.html) go up to 37 used bits (so 2^38 - 1 ?) but beware as it will use a lot of your CPU.

**/!\ I AM NOT LIABLE FOR ANY DAMAGE IF YOU GO FOR 2^(2^37).**