# SPOJ -Small factorials

Tags: c

http://www.spoj.com/problems/FCTRL2/
My code is showing compilation error in Spoj,although running accurate in my compiler.
**IDE - Codeblocks **

```
int cal(int );


int main()
{
  int i,t;
  int n[100];
  scanf("%d",&t);
   for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
       scanf("%d",&n[i]);
    }

for(i=0;i<t;i++)
{
  printf("%d",cal(n[i]));
  printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
int cal(int x)
{
  int j,a=1;
 for(j=x;j>=1;j--)
 {
 a=a*j;


 }
 return a;


}
```

Comment: A simple q: what if input for `t` greater than `100`? Also, please indent your code properly. Can you please post the `error`s too?

Comment: You must be able to compute `100!`, but can not be represented in your use simple `int`.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. This isn't readable.

Comment: Yes  you guys are right I have to include it in long int.

Comment: it is not enough even `long int`. You need to implement a simple multiple length arithmetic.

Comment: 100! = 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000

Comment: Could you cite the sources to study it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17039284/971127 you customize(change cell size and without malloc & realloc) it for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` and `scanf` are not defined. You need to include the `stdio` library.

I get this error locally:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:8:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘scanf’
         scanf("%d",&t);
         ^
test.c:16:16: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
                printf("%d",cal(n[i]));
                ^
```

Comment: Really do you think this is the issue?

Comment: @Gopi Maybe not, but you never know !!. :-) Let's wait for OP to post his/her _error_ (s).

Comment: WELL I have not included the header files intentionally and yes "data type" is the error.

Answer (score 0):

For every integer input you have to calculate the factorial. This is very simple in languages like python or java which have built-in support for big integer types. Although it gives tough time for people using C / C++ or languages that do not have a built-in biginteger type.

Now, the maximum number that can be stored in an unsigned 32 bit integer is 2 ^ 32 – 1 and in an unsigned 64 bit integer is 2 ^ 64 – 1. Something like 100! has over 150 decimal digits. The data types mentioned earlier can store numbers having at most 9 and 19 decimal digits respectively. So, you need to find a way to store the 150+ digits that we will get as the answer. Think of using arrays to store each decimals.